# How to post list of images to Dio?

Tags: flutter

The endpoint's signature is:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Post([FromForm]List<IFormFile> imgFile)
```

Tried with Postman, this works just fine.

[image]

This code works:

```
List<String> ss = partInfo.rejectionPicturesPath;
FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
  "imgFile": await MultipartFile.fromFile(ss[0]),
});
```

Now the question is how do I write it so that I can send it as a list...

```
// Don't work
List<FormData> formData = [];
await Future.forEach(partInfo.rejectionPicturesPath, (p) async {
  formData.add(FormData.fromMap({
    "imgFile" : await MultipartFile.fromFile(p),
  }));
});

// Don't work
List<String> ss = partInfo.rejectionPicturesPath;
FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
  "imgFile": await MultipartFile.fromFile(ss[0]),
  "imgFile": await MultipartFile.fromFile(ss[1]),
});

// Don't work either
FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
  "imgFile": [
    await MultipartFile.fromFile(ss[0]),
    await MultipartFile.fromFile(ss[1]),
  ]
});
```

I send it this way:

```
BaseOptions options = BaseOptions(
  contentType: "multipart/form-data"
);
var dio = Dio(options);
(dio.httpClientAdapter as DefaultHttpClientAdapter).onHttpClientCreate = (HttpClient client) {
  client.badCertificateCallback = (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
  return client;
};

// I'm stuck here trying to build a list of the images, see non working codes above

var resp = await dio.post(baseUrl, data: data);
```

How do I send a list of images? I'm pretty sure this can be done, since Postman can post it just fine. How do I write this into Dart's code?

Comment: Are you getting any kind of error?

Comment: No. The request gets through, the backend receives it... except it's empty. Sending a single element like this: FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({ "imgFile": await MultipartFile.fromFile(ss[0]) }); works just fine. I don't know how to send this as a list.

Comment: Ok I got this, could you please upload the FormData class code here, I want to see the fromData function.

Comment: See the updated codes. Is that what you want to see?

Comment: I want to see FormData class code. Because you are using a map and and giving same key so it will take the last value.

Comment: FormData class is from dio's package, you sure you want to see that? Anyway: https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/blob/master/dio/lib/src/form_data.dart

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209163/discussion-between-jagraj-singh-and-farid).

Answer (score 1):

Managed to get this working:

```
List<String> ss = partInfo.rejectionPicturesPath;
var data = FormData();
data.files.addAll([
  MapEntry(
    "imgFile",
    await MultipartFile.fromFile(ss[0]),
  ),
  MapEntry(
    "imgFile",
    await MultipartFile.fromFile(ss[1]),
  ),
]);
```